# Eclipse compilation error referencing a maven project that uses shade

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have a Maven Project A (thirdparty) that uses the [Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). I have another Project B that depends on it and refers to some of the shaded classes. If I have both projects open, there are compilation errors because Eclipse can't find these classes, since they don't exist in A/target/classes.

Is there a good way for me to set up Eclipse so that B looks into .m2 for Project A's classes, rather than just A/target?

Comment: Have you tried to disable _<project>_ → _Properties_ → _Maven_ → [   ] _Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects_?

Comment: @Gerold It's a good idea. But I have a problem with this solution. I found I have about 50 projects in my workspace that all depend on each other, and I don't want to disable that feature on all of them. I'd like to either only disable workspace dependency on Project A (which is at the bottom of the dependency hierarchy), or let Project A resolve from the workspace and fall back to .m2. There is a good discussion about it at http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg03160.html. It sounds like it's a limitation in Eclipse :(

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the shaded dependencies of A as direct dependencies of B with [scope `provided`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) should do the trick:

> ***scope:***
>
> ***provided** - this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it at runtime. It is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.*

Since you have *"about 50 projects"* it's probably a good idea to introduce a new POM inheritance level:

- Your top POM

  - Project A

    - New POM declaring shaded dependencies as `provided`

      - Projects like B that depend on A's shaded dependencies
  - 50 POMs of grey